# Las funciones de php me trabajan de diferentes formas en distintas hosting

Tags: php, sqlite, cpanel, godaddy

Soy un poco nuevo en esto pero les indicare que sucede
1)Tengo un programa de php con javascript, jquery, bootstrap, su respectivo css y los archivos smtp para enviar correo, en mi localhost todo funciona correctamente, envia correos etc.. se complica es al momento de subirlo al hosting
2)Tengo de prueba a 3 hosting.... Godaddy, CaracasHosting y uno gratuito llamado zz.com.ve
3)GoDaddy no tiene por defecto el modo rewrite activado, algo que es de vital importancia para el proyecto por ende no nos sirve, CaracasHosting si tiene activado ese modo pero al momento de querer iniciar sesion etc.. por ejemplo al validar el usuario, simplemente se queda en ese archivo php si hacaer nada, puede registrar y de hecho si vas al lugar como deberia hacer al momento de validar al usuario este lo valida etc.. pero pues no cumple sus funciones como deberia, Este es el error de los log

```
[03-Mar-2020 01:13:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/globalli/public_html/directorio/validar.php:8) in /home/globalli/public_html/directorio/validar.php on line 11
```

3)Por ultimo tenemos al servicio web gratuito y que creen? Este si casi por completo sus funciones como lo hace en mi localhost....El envio del correo no funciona en ninguno de los 3 tengo entendido que eso es cuestion de hablar con la empresa a ver como configurarlo
Si alguien puede orientarme seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: No entiendo, cual es la pregunta? si los hostings trabajan diferente es porque estan configurados diferentes...

Comment: No puedes fijar la sesión.pq la sesión en php va en un header, el header --set-cookie que se convierte en el ID de tu sesión..Tiene que haber un problema en las plantillas, por ejemplo un espacio en blanco antes de <?php

Comment: exacto @ffflabs a eso me refiero, pero estoy verificando y los archivos en los que entra para validar al usuario no tienen esos errores, eso mismo habia leido por otros lados pero nada que ver, o almenos eso verifique

Comment: Debes tener en tu cuerpo del código algún header. Lo correcto es que manejes los headers al inicio del código.

Comment: @Bicho si amigo porfin solucione ese pequeño problema, ahora viene lo grande, que no realiza las funciones de agregar a la base de datos, este edita y elimina pero no agrega, no se que hacer porque es en ese hosting que no me esta funcionando

Comment: Formula una nueva pregunta agregando el código.